# Clearing ObservableCollection and Notifying UI

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I'm trying to clear my ObservableCollection `MyTruckCollection` of all of it's items. The issue I have is that it is not updating my UI after the collection has cleared of all items.

I've tried clearing it with the following ways:

`MyTruckCollection.Clear();`

```
foreach (var item in MyTruckCollection.ToList())
    MyTruckCollection.Remove(item);
```

I've tried this extension method:

```
    public static void RemoveAll<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (condition(collection[i]))
            {
                collection.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

And used it like this:

`MyTruckCollection.RemoveAll(x => x.TruckId != 0);`

They all remove all of the items, but my UI isn't being notified of the changes. Is there a way to notify my UI when I clear all of the data within the collection?

NOTE: I also have PropertyChanged implemented on my MyTruckCollection.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote...can you explain why?

Comment: After `MyTruckCollection.Clear();` try write `RaisePropertyChanged("MyTruckCollection")` or `OnPropertyChanged("MyTruckCollection");`

Comment: MyTruckCollection is binded OneTime or OneWay in the UI? In `{Binding ...}` by default is OneTime, and in `{x:Bind ...}` by default is OneTime.

Comment: And revise also the Set of MyTruckCollection. Maybe there are an if that stop propagating this changes.

Comment: Thanks for you comments @dachibox I'm just away from my pc atm but will test as soon as I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution.

The issue was that I was clearing all the items in the `MyTruckCollection` but the DataGrid that I was using wasn't updated with it. All of the items were still being displayed that was removed.

So to fix it I just had to set the DataGrid's ItemSource to the cleared `MyTruckCollection` after I cleared the collection and the DataGrid was cleared.

```
MyTruckCollection.Clear();
dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = MyTruckCollection;
```